# ST_GeomFromGeoJSON and ST_Intersects performance issues

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using both functions in a query like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('a valid json'), boundingbox) ORDER BY uuid, last_update_date;
```

DBA told me that using ST_GeomFromGeoJSON inside WHERE could be a reason for the slowness.

If I use 2 queries instead of the current one, should I get better results? I mean something like:

```
letsImagineAVariable = select ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('a valid json');
```

And then run:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ST_Intersects(letsImagineAVariable, boundingbox) ORDER BY uuid, last_update_date;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "If I use 2 queries instead of the current one, should I get better results?"  I doubt it.  Did you try it?  Did you get better results?  Do you you still have a question?

Comment: Please add the execution plan by running explain analyze

Comment: It's nearly impossible to give a decent performance advice without seeing the query plan. Add the query plan and the indexes you have in this table, if any.